# Font identification for all-caps "Schiffer-Gilde e.V" logo

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I am searching for the font in the below all-caps "Schiffer-Gilde e.V" logo I need to modify for our association.

[image: Schiffer-Gilde e.V logo]

The closest that the automatic free identification services (https://www.whatfontis.com/, https://www.fontsquirrel.com, https://www.myfonts.com/) came to were *Riccione TS Bold* and *ITC Serif Pro Ultra*, but those are clearly not enough on the drastic serif style.

I am searching for a paid or free font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *looks like* it's a custom alteration of an existing font, though I didn't pore through alternate glyphs the closest match I found was pretty darn close out-of-the-box - look especially at the formation of the R, C, L & V. I think if you start with that and then add custom work for the extensions on the D, G & V, you'll be there.

[Cinzel Black at WhatFontIs](https://www.whatfontis.com/FF_Cinzel-Black.font?text=DIESCHFRGLV)

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also available at Google fonts: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Cinzel

Comment: You are right, this font is pretty darn close. Thanks for your opinion on the the custom alteration part.